# Storing data from CSV file to MAP in C++

Tags: c++, file, csv

I know this is very similar to "how to read data from CSV file in C++". 
please bear me. 
I have constructor in a class

```
class DatFlow{
public: 
DataFlow(uint8_t Data_flow_id, uint8_t data_type, 
                uint8_t priority, uint8_t window_size, uint16_t send_ttl,
                uint16_t sequence_ttl, uint16_t guard_ttl, uint8_t retry_count, 
                uint8_t repeat_count, bool ack);
...
};
```

I have a map for the data flow declared as

```
std::map<uint8_t, DataFlow> Data_flow_map_;
```

Upon invoking DataFlowManager
//like below

```
DataFlow::DataFlowManager(id, ttl)
{
 Data_flow_map_[2]  = DatFlow( 2, Traffic0,  2,  8, 0, 500, 300, 3, 0, false);

        Data_flow_map_[13] = DataFlow(13, Traffic1,  2,  8, 0, 500, 300, 3, 0, false);
        Data_flow_map_[14] = DataFlow(14, Traffic2,  1,  8, 0, 500, 300, 3, 0, false);
}
```

Now, instead of hard coding the Map, I would like to read the data from a CSV and put it into map.

```
The csv file contains could look like 
2, Traffic0,  2,  8, 0, 500, 300, 3, 0, false
13, Traffic1,  2,  8, 0, 500, 300, 3, 0, false
14, Traffic1,  1,  8, 0, 500, 300, 3, 0, false
```

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Which field or fields are the key?  The `std::map` requires a key field.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many ways to achieve this.
The basic algorithm:
1. Read from CSV file into structure (rather than using hardcoded constructor).
2. Insert into `std::map`.

Searching for "stackoverflow c++ read file csv" will reveal a plethora of examples on how to overload `operator>>` to read data members from a CSV file.

I recommend creating a default constructor.

Comment: Hi Thomas,I ended up using the approach you suggested. which was to copy cell data to structure. once the structure is filled, I pass data to constructor and finally to map.